# Finding all minimal surfaces of specific form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I want to find all minimal surfaces of the form $z = \phi(x) + \psi(y)$ over some region $D$ in the xy-plane.

This should be equivalent to minimizing the functional

$$ J[z] = \iint_D \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}\,dxdy. $$

The Euler-Lagrange equation is then

$$ F_z - \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}F_{z_x} - \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}F_{z_y} = 0 \Rightarrow $$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \Bigg(\frac{z_x}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}}\Bigg) + 
\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \Bigg(\frac{z_y}{\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}}\Bigg) = 0 \Rightarrow $$

$$ \frac{z_{xx}(1+z_y^2)}{(1+z_x^2+z_y^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{z_{yy}(1+z_x^2)}{(1+z_x^2+z_y^2)^{3/2}} = 0 \Rightarrow $$

$$ z_{xx}(1+z_y^2) + z_{yy}(1+z_x^2) = 0 \Rightarrow $$

$$ \phi''(x)(1+\psi'(y)^2) + \psi''(y)(1+\phi'(x)^2) = 0. $$

Now I don't really know how to attack this equation and I do not recognize its form. I have tried separation of variables but don't know how to handle the squared terms. I can set either $\phi = 0$ or $\psi=0$ and obtain a solution
$$ z = Ax + By +C$$
which represents a plane. But I cannot be confident that this respresents all solutions to the given problem.

My question is thus: What is an efficient approach to solving this equation, and how to be certain when I have found all solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi''(x)(1+\psi'(y)^2) + \psi''(y)(1+\phi'(x)^2) = 0.$$
$$\frac {\phi''(x)}{(1+\phi'(x)^2)}=-\frac {\psi''(y) }{(1+\psi'(y)^2)} $$
Both functions depends on different variables so
$$\frac {\phi''(x)}{(1+\phi'(x)^2)}=-\lambda $$
$$\frac {\psi''(y) }{(1+\psi'(y)^2)}=\lambda$$
Integrate both equations:
$$\int \frac {d\phi'(x)}{(1+\phi'(x)^2)}=-\lambda \int dx$$
$$\int \frac {d\psi'(y) }{(1+\psi'(y)^2)}=\lambda\int dy$$
And:
$$\int \dfrac {dw}{1+w^2}=\arctan ( w ) +C$$

Comment: Thank you! It was the integration step that got me confused.

Comment: You're welcomed @Engelmark it's just the arctan function...